# Codeigniter search results with pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hi I need hel I'm trying to get pagination with search results.
I don't know what I am doing wrong. Because my results don't show up.

Here is my Model

```
function search_posts($query, $pagina, $por_pagina)
{

        $this->db->select();
        $this->db->from('posts');
        $this->db->like("post_title", $query, 'both');
        $this->db->or_like("post", $query, 'both');
        $this->db->order_by('post_id', 'desc');
        $this->db->limit($pagina, $por_pagina);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();

}

public function contar_filas()
{
    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $query = $this->db->count_all_results();
    return $query;
}
```

Here is my Controller

```
public function buscar()
{

    $this->load->model('M_Articulos');
    $data['posts'] = '';
    $data['sin_resultados'] = '';
    $query = trim($this->input->get('query', TRUE));
    if (sizeof($query) == 0)
    {
        show_404();
    }
    if ($query)
    {
        if ($this->uri->segment(3))
        {
            $pagina = $this->uri_segment(3);
        }
        else
        {
            $pagina = 0;
        }
        $por_pagina = 4;
        $data['posts'] = $this->M_Articulos->search_posts($query, $pagina, $por_pagina);
        if ($data['posts'] != FALSE)
        {
            $data['posts'] = $this->M_Articulos->search_posts($query, $pagina, $por_pagina);
            $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'admin/buscar?query=' . $query;
            $config['per_page'] = $por_pagina;
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->M_Articulos->contar_filas();
            $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
            $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
            $config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
            $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        }
        else
        {
            $data['sin_resultados'] = 'nada';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $data['sin_resultados'] = 'nada';
    }


    $this->load->view('admin/layouts/header');
    $this->load->view('admin/modules/buscar', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/layouts/footer');
}
```

does anyone know how to make it work?
I'm going to be more specific. What i want is that when i search somethin in search page there is a pagination. Thanks

Comment: follow this https://github.com/miazyparvez33/pagination-with-search-value-codeigniter